# Criar um novo registro com base em outro com Entity

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, entity-framework

Preciso adicionar umas colunas a uma base de dados da seguinte forma:

1. guardo uma linha da bd numa variável

   ```
    Market novo = new market();
    novo = context.Markets.where(blabla).First();
   ```
2. altero uma coluna da linha

   ```
    novo.ParentID = 50;
   ```
3. guardo a linha na BD, porém dá erro pois o chave da linha que estou a adicionar já existe e não sei como faço para zerar essa chave no meu código.

   ```
    context.AddObject(novo); // da erro por causa da PrimaryKey
   ```

Comment: você só tem que alterar o registro, e não adicionar um novo, o erro aí é apenas na sua lógica... e, eu acho que não é ADO.NET

Comment: Não há erro nenhum, é esse o objetivo. Essa tabela é uma árvore com hierarquias, o que ueu quero fazer é buscar uma sub-categoria(linha), é apenas mudar o ParentID e adicioná-la na BD novamente, mas agora vai pertencer a outra categoria pai

Answer (score 2):

Se a necessidade é criar um novo objeto então o que deve fazer é copiar as propriedades do objeto base e não atribuir completamente o objeto, assim:

```
Market novo = new market();
var objAux = context.Markets.where(blabla).First();

novo.prop1 = objAux.prop1;
novo.prop2 = objAux.prop2;
novo.prop3 = objAux.prop3;
novo.prop4 = NovoValor;

context.AddObject(novo);
```

Comment: O objetivo é incluir um objeto novo, por causa da coluna alterada. Preciso de ter os dois na base de dados, o original + alterado

Comment: Modifiquei a resposta para essa necessidade. Adapte ao seu código.

Comment: Okay, eu queria evitar fazer isso mas vai ter de ser 

Comment: Orientação a objeto é assim, se você atribuir um objeto para o outro  ele vai atribuir por referência e não por valor. Em algumas linguagens isso pode ser especificado, em outras isso é automático.

Answer (score 0):

Também pode fazer uso do `MemberWiseClone`. Esse método existe na classe `Object` mas está com acesso `protected` por isso, se lhe for útil pode disponibilizar num método:

```
public Market Clone(){
    return base.MemberwiseClone() as Market;
}
```

E usar da seguinte forma:

```
var objAux = context.Markets.where(blabla).First().Clone();
```

Tenha em atencáo que o `MemberwiseClone`  faz uma cópia do objeto integral, ou seja as referencias para outros objetos sao mantidas.